# Dedicated WHM/Cpanel Hosting

Tags: magento, hosting, cpanel, whm

I am currently paying around 80UK GBP a month for a VPS hosting account with heart internet. I have a 3 core and 3gb of ram with 4-5 magento sites running on seperate cpanels, I am finding it very slow.

My question is does anyone recommend any good hosting companies for around the same budget with WHM/Cpanel which will run my sites faster?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you're confident with managing your own servers then I'd suggest moving over to a cloud solution like Rackspace or Amazon. You could set up a load balancer and then scale the number of servers that handle your web traffic or alternatively set up separate servers with public IPs for different sites if you run multiple sites. I would recommend a Load Balancer with multiple servers so you have redundancy.

If you'd rather not manage your own solution then consider UKWSD's managed VPS. Their top tier VPS package is £76p/m. While it doesn't have quite as much RAM, it does have 12 cores (2 priority) and I have always been impressed by the speed of their servers and the level of support they offer.

http://ukwebsolutionsdirect.co.uk/managed-cpanel-vps.php